# TextBox style is setting for all Textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made a style for a few specific Textboxes in my application and placed this inside of my `App.xaml`:

```
<Style x:Name="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>
```

After doing that it set the style for every textbox in my application. I didn't even set this style on any textbox yet.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `x:Key` (and reference using [`StaticResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750950%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), otherwise it's used by `TargetType`, hence applying to all `TextBoxes`.

This is a special implicit behaviour, i.e. if a `Style` is defined as a child of a `ResourceDictionary` without a key, the `TargetType` is used as key. There are other such implicit rules, e.g. `DataTemplate` creates special data template keys which then also apply the template implicitly where applicable.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I totally did not see that I wrote x:Name instead of x:key. Thanks, lol. I think I need a break

Comment: @Insane: Haha, found that odd as well.